# How to get amount of records of a specific ID in a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to check which users have the most records in a database. So every user has a specific Id, and that Id is used as a reference in a few tables.

There are a few tables that contain a column UserId, like the table Exams, Answers, Questions, Classes, etc. Is it possible to count all the records with a specific UserId in all those tables?

Comment: The answer is YES. E.g. you can do a UNION ALL in a derived table.

Comment: Yes possible, using joins or union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as (
select rowsCount = count(*) from A where UserId = 1
union all
select rowsCount = count(*) from B where UserId = 1
union all
select rowsCount = count(*) from C where UserId = 1
)
select sum(rowsCount) from cte
```

Comment: Do `UNION ALL`, in case there are the same number of rows in the tables!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in this way:

```
With AllRecords AS
(
    SELECT TableName = 'Exams'
    FROM dbo.Exams
    WHERE UserId = @YouruserID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TableName = 'Answers'
    FROM dbo.Answers
    WHERE UserId = @YouruserID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TableName = 'Questions'
    FROM dbo.Questions
    WHERE UserId = @YouruserID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TableName = 'Classes'
    FROM dbo.Classes
    WHERE UserId = @YouruserID
) 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllRecords
```

The table-name is not needed if you just want the count, it's just for the case that you want to know the source.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
SELECT Count(E.ID) + Count(A.ID) + Count(Q.ID) + Count(C.ID) AS SumofAllCount
FROM dbo.Exams E
LEFT JOIN dbo.Answers A ON A.UserId = E.UserId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Questions Q ON Q.UserId = E.UserId
LEFT JOIN dbo.Classes C ON C.UserId = E.UserId
WHERE E.UserId = @YouruserID
GROUP BY E.UserId
```